# Use of generic-type for a member of struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have a `struct`:

```
struct MyStruct {

    const unsigned short *ptr = nullptr;

    /* above pointer might also be:
    const unsigned int   *ptr = nullptr; 
    */

    // ...
};
```

I use the `struct` as a member of a class:

```
class MyClass
{
    // ...

private:
    MyStruct m_struct;
}
```

Inside member functions of `MyClass`, I want to be able to have a switch like this:

```cpp
void MyClass::myFunc()
{
    // ...

    switch(myDataType) {

    case USHORT:
        m_struct.ptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>(myDataPtr);
        break;

    case UINT:
        m_struct.ptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int   *>(myDataPtr);
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }
}
```

Currently, the above `switch` is not possible due to incompatible types.

I cannot figure out how I should define my `struct` with a proper `template`, so that I would be able to do the above `switch` on class member function.

Comment: What is `myData`? Did you mean `ptr`?

Comment: While using such type-switching functionality as shown in `myFunc` could be a sign of bad design, there are cases where it could be useful. Anyway, instead of templates I think more along the lines of *unions*.

Comment: `T*` or `void*`

Comment: Did you already have a look at `std::variant`?

Answer (score 4):

You can make both of them class template. Then no need to use `switch`. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
struct MyStruct {

    const T *ptr = nullptr;

    // ...
};

template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    // ...

private:
    MyStruct<T> m_struct;
};

template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::myFunc()
{
    // ...

    m_struct.ptr = reinterpret_cast<const T *>(myData);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is more elegant =) But for some reason, code doesn't have access to type `T` (doesn't know what it is), until after code is inside `MyClass::myFunc`. Maybe I need to change more things ...

Comment: @user3405291 `T` is the template typename declared before the class or function. I would advise you to read a tutorial about what are C++ templates and how to use them, because it seems that it is what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

[`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (c++17, else use boost one) might help you:

```
struct MyStruct {

    std::variant<const unsigned short*, const unsigned int*> ptr{std::in_place_index_t<0>, nullptr}; 

    // ...
};
```

and then

```
void MyClass::myFunc()
{
    // ...

    switch(myDataType) {
    case USHORT:
        m_struct.ptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>(myDataPtr);
        break;

    case UINT:
        m_struct.ptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int *>(myDataPtr);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    // ...
}
```

or even simply `m_struct.ptr = myDataPtr;` if `myDataPtr` is a `std::variant` too.

[`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) might also help instead of `switch`.

Comment: Thanks =) I'm going to try it

Comment: I realized I'm limited to C++14, I will try it whenever I'm able to use C++17 =)

Comment: in C++14, you have `boost::variant` which is very similar to std one.

Answer (score 0):

Althouth @songyuanyao answer is more elegant, I cannot use it since I don't know type `T` at compile time. Therefore I'm currently using the following workaround. I'm not sure if it is the best:

```cpp
struct MyStruct {

    const unsigned short *ptr_ushort = nullptr;

    // consider the other type:
    const unsigned int   *ptr_uint   = nullptr; 

    // To know what type we have:
    TypeEnum ptr_type;

    // ...
};
```

Then, I implemented my switch like this:

```cpp
void MyClass::myFunc()
{
    // ...

    switch(myDataType) {

    case USHORT:
        m_struct.ptr_ushort = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>(myDataPtr);
        m_struct.ptr_type   = TypeEnum::USHORT;
        break;

    case UINT:
        m_struct.ptr_uint   = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int   *>(myDataPtr);
        m_struct.ptr_type   = TypeEnum::UINT;
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }

    // ...
}
```